# How we can find the distance between two points inside a cluster?

Tags: python, geometry, cluster-analysis

I have to find the distance between two points inside the cluster. I have generated the clusters through the following code:

```
X = np.arange(0,10.2,0.16)
Y = np.arange(0,10.2,0.16)
A = np.arange(0,2, 0.005) 
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
z = np.zeros(x.shape)

x0 = X.mean()
y0 = Y.mean()
b_center1 = [2,8]
b_center2 = [6,2]
r1=0.1*X.max()
r2=0.1*X.max()

for i in range(1, len(X)):
    for j in range(1, len(Y)):
        dist = pdist(np.array([[X[i],Y[j]],b_center1]))
        if (dist[0] < r1):
            z[i][j]=1
        dist = pdist(np.array([[X[i],Y[j]],b_center2]))
        if (dist[0] < r2):
            z[i][j]=1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.scatter(x, y, z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.draw()
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
plt.show()
```

[This is the clusters I have obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeLZ7.jpg)

[d is the distance I have to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pupct.jpg)

Comment: That distance is the shortest distance between any point and all others. Nothing easier.

Comment: 1. Take one x values between xmax and xmin. 2. for that x value sort all y values. Then take the difference of first two sorted y values.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the `z` array, which is `64*64` matric with `0 and 1`.
Get the x_index, y_index where `z==1`

```py
np.where(z == 1)
```

```
(array([ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  ...),
 array([47, 48, 49, 50, 51, ...]))
```

So it can be seen, for x=7, z=1 for y=47, y=48, y=50 etc.
So we have to calculate the distance between `(7,47)` and `(7,48)`
So, the distance is `Y[48] - Y[47]` or `Y[49] - Y[48]`

```py
print(Y[48] - Y[47])
>>> 0.15999999999999925 # i.e. around 0.16
```

And that is simply because you are line spacing by `0.16`, your points are separated by 0.16, so you don't have to calculate at all. :p

X = np.arange(0,10.2,`0.16`)

Y = np.arange(0,10.2,`0.16`)

A = np.arange(0,2, 0.005)